# Will using all the Google web tools boost trust of a website or help SEO?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I have using a single Google account and using that I created Google webmasters account so my website uses single User account access all the service provided by The google like adwords, adsense,webtools, google Map etc.  Will this increases trust of my website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have thought this question was asked before, but I can't find it. I also can't find Google's definitive answer on the subject. (Update - see Su's answer for where they say that.) However I'm pretty sure that the answer is no. If the answer was yes, then people would do all those things to increase their ranking and the quality of search results would go down, which wouldn't help Google in the long run.

The tools provided by Webmaster Tools can help you increase the quality and relevance of your site, but just signing up for it won't do that - you have to put in the work to use the tools.

Comment: Not only that, Google would surely be reprimanded for being anti-competitive.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, no:

> Verification doesn't affect PageRank or affect your site's performance in Google's search results.

–from the Webmaster Tools "[adding a site](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34592&from=35181&rd=1)" page.

Comment: I knew it was there somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

No, but by using all the available tools you will be able to diagnose any issues on the site, which can help you boost your site's performance over time.